# "Out of" vs "outside" of city

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I would like to know what would be the correct sentence here. I just want to say that I left the city on the weekend.

> I went out of the city on Saturday.
>     I went outside the city on
>   Saturday.

Comment: FWIW, I'd recommend: "I left the city on Saturday."

Comment: All three sentences are grammatically correct (although "out of" is a more dubious way of phrasing). How long did you leave the city for?

Comment: I am asking because I know that "go out of" something means to lose an ability so I was not sure here..

Comment: What? Never heard that usage. "Run out of" can mean "exhaust a supply of" -- running out of toilet paper is not a good experience. But "go out of"? +1 for @J.R.'s comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentences are fine. As J.R. mentioned, it's better to say,

> **I left the city on Saturday**.

*Out of* is better suited in situations like,

> **I am out of town right now, I will get back to you when I return.**

Although *outside the city* is grammatically correct, it sounds a bit unorthodox in this context.

Answer (score 2):

The colloquial way to say this would be as follows:

> I went out of town this Saturday.

or

> I left town this Saturday.

and to talk about going out of town in the future:

> I'm going out of town this Saturday.
>
> I'll be leaving town this Saturday.

Comment: I prefer 'I'll be out of town next Saturday'. (Absent, unavailable).