# Appropriate preposition to go with "outside their comfort zone"

Tags: grammaticality

Is the preposition "of" necessary in the phrase "outside their comfort zone"?

Comment: It's usually one or the other of *"**out of** their comfort zone"* or (less commonly) *"**outside** their comfort zone"*.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Outside" or "outside of"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9700/outside-or-outside-of) Or [“Out of” vs “outside” of city](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73372/out-of-vs-outside-of-city)